# Call Controller Function from Select Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering how I can call a function in my controller depending on the option that is selected in a  menu.

For instance, using ng-click, when a  is clicked, I can call the function. I want to do something similar upon selection in AngularJS.

```
<select class="dropdown">  
  <option value="">Menu</option> 
  <option ng-click="open()">Settings</option> // call open() when Settings is selected
</select>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `ng-model` and `$watch` for a change in that model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ng-change with ng-model:

```
 <select ng-model="model" ng-change="onSelect()" >
```

Where onSelect() is a method on your scope.

Comment: Thank you! ng-model is incredibly powerful :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<select ng-model="whatever">
     <option value="settings">Settings</option>
</select>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('whatever', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     if (newValue == 'settings') { 
         doSomething();
     }
});
```